# Trouble with refreshing countdown in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have countdown on my [site](http://project-welcome.ugu.pl/a.php) which fails to refresh itself.

Code: http://pastebin.com/DNjb0WSN

```
window.onload = function() {
    idElement = "time";
    document.getElementById(idElement).innerHTML = 
        "<?php countdown(21,00,00,9,15,2012) ?>";

    setInterval("document.getElementById(idElement).innerHTML = 
        '<?php countdown(21,00,00,9,15,2012) ?>'", 1000);
};

// ...

<?php
    function countdown($godzina, $minuta, $sekunda, $miesiac, $dzien, $rok) {
        $target = mktime($godzina, $minuta, $sekunda, $miesiac, $dzien, $rok);
        $now = time();
        $sekundy = ($target - $now);
        // $sekundy =(int) ($sekundy) ;

        $check = 0;
        if ($sekundy > 0) {
            if ($check == 0) {
                if ($sekundy <= 10000) {
                    // zmien klase
                    $check = 1;
                }
            }
            $hours = floor($sekundy / 3600);
            $minutes = floor(($sekundy / 60) - ($hours * 60));
            $seconds = floor(($sekundy) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60));


            if ($hours < 10) $hours = '0'.$hours;

            if ($minutes < 10) $minutes = '0'.$minutes;

            if ($seconds < 10) $seconds = '0'.$seconds;

            $all = $hours." : ".$minutes." : ".$seconds;
            echo $all;
        }
        else {
            echo "Aukcja zakończona!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: [Please include the relevant code in the qustion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114942/153691). If the external site goes down, the question here on StackOverflow is not nearly as valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Because the countdown is not implemented in javascript but php. If you need the countdown to work on the client you need to implement it in javascript or poll the server(**NOT RECOMMENDED**).

**The web is stateless, does that ring any bells?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using a countdown library written in JavaScript and parametrize it from PHP:
http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm